# how to fetch id outside the while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a project in which i have to perform the below given functionality. What I'm doing is that i am fetching the id of some fields..and echoing them inside the while loop. and its giving me 1 2 3. What i want to do is to print these fetched id's outside the wile loop. But its giving only the last id(3). I've tried using arrays,but still its not working..Some one please tell me how to do it right. By using `foreach` or whatever that helps doing the task..

Thank you in advance...

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","user");

$sqlia="SELECT * FROM `fields` WHERE `workspace_id`='$workspace_id'";
$querys= mysqli_query($con,$sqlia);
if($querys)
{
    while($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($querys))
    {
    $rows['field_id'];
    echo $field_id=$rows['field_id']."<br>";
    }

echo "Outside the while".$field_id;

}
else
{
    echo "Didnt work".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: `$field_id` is being set to the value of `$rows['field_id']` each time it loops through. So logically, the last value of when it is being overwritten would be what you get outside of the loop.

Comment: @Blake isn't there a way to get all the values that loop through???

Comment: Yes. Try `var_dump()`ing what `mysqli_fetch_assoc($querys)` actually contains. Maybe that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `array` to store ids.

Try

```
if($querys)
{
    $ids = array();
    while($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($querys))
    {
        $rows['field_id'];
        $ids [] = $rows['field_id'];
        echo $field_id = $rows['field_id']."<br>";
    }

    echo "Outside the while".$field_id;
    print_r($ids);
}
```

Comment: Bravo..that worked...by print_r $ids; it was returning arrays with its key,,so i replace it with echo $ids[0]; echo $ids[1]; echo $ids[2]; and now its fulfilling my requirements. Thankssssss

Comment: @MashhoodAli I'm glad it works for you :)

Comment: If it works for you then you should vote up @MashhoodAli

Comment: i had voted it up several hours ago..